# Dynamic div dimensions: lightbox gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, gallery, lightbox

I'm creating a website where I have a series of images with different dimensions that are being placed in a lightbox gallery.

Sorry for the long read in advance.... the code is as follows:

http://jsfiddle.net/djtiii/Sas94/1/

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <h1>simple lightbox w/ slideshow (images only)</h1>

    <p>those image links i was talking about:</p>
    <ul id="paintings">
        <li> <a title="The Hills" href="http://www.artmajeur.com/files/oksana-veber/images/artworks/100x100/6683281_the-hils-100-100-cm-acrilic-on-canvas-1998-thumb.jpg" class="lightboxTrigger">
            on
            </a>

        </li>
        <li> <a title="Pixelisa" href="http://piq.codeus.net/static/media/userpics/piq_2313_400x400.png" class="lightboxTrigger">
            two
            </a>

        </li>
        <li> <a title="Vase" href="http://andyinoman.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/story-no-5-the-loosing-battle.jpg?w=500" class="lightboxTrigger">
            three
            </a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* page styles */
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #efefef;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 25px;
    border-top: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    text-align: left;
}
/* lightbox styles */
 #lightbox {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#lightbox p {
    text-align: right;
    color: #fff;
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#lightbox img {
    max-width: 940px;
}
/* slideshow styles */
 #slideshow {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 600px;
    height: 350px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#slideshow ul > li {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    list-style: none;
}
.nav {
    display: none;
}
.prev, .next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    background: rgba(100, 100, 100, .5);
    padding: .25em .5em;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.next {
    right: 10px;
}
.prev {
    left: 10px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var current, size;

    $('.lightboxTrigger').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var slideNum = $('.lightboxTrigger').index(this);

        if ($('#lightbox').length > 0) {
            $('#lightbox').fadeIn(300);
            $('#content').html('<img src="' + href + '" />');
        } else {

            var hgt = $(this).attr('height');
            var wid = $(this).attr('width');

            var lightbox =
                '<div id="lightbox">' +
                '<p>X</p>' +
                '<div id="slideshow">' +
                '<ul></ul>' +
                '<div class="nav">' +
                '<a href="#prev" class="prev slide-nav"><</a>' +
                '<a href="#next" class="next slide-nav">></a>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>';


            $('body').append(lightbox);

            $('#paintings').find('.lightboxTrigger').each(function () {

                var href = $(this).attr('href');
                var title = $(this).attr('title');
                $('#slideshow ul').append(
                    '<li>' +
                    '<img src="' + href + '">' +
                    '<h5>' + title + '</h5>' +
                    '</li>');
            });

            $('#lightbox').hide().fadeIn(300);
        }

        size = $('#slideshow ul > li').length;

        $('#slideshow ul > li').hide();
        $('#slideshow ul > li:eq(' + slideNum + ')').show();

        current = slideNum;
    });

    $('body').on('click', '#lightbox', function () {
        $('#lightbox').fadeOut(300);
    });

    $('body').on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $('.nav').fadeIn(300);
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $('.nav').fadeOut(300);
        }
    }, '#slideshow');

    $('body').on('click', '.slide-nav', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        var $this = $(this);
        var dest;

        if ($this.hasClass('prev')) {
            dest = current - 1;
            if (dest < 0) {
                dest = size - 1;
            }
        } else {
            dest = current + 1;
            if (dest > size - 1) {
                dest = 0;
            }
        }

        $('#slideshow ul > li:eq(' + current + ')').fadeOut(750);
        $('#slideshow ul > li:eq(' + dest + ')').fadeIn(750);

        current = dest;
    });

});
```

The issue with this code is that the `div id=slideshow`'s dimensions are not dynamic to the dimensions of the images. I'm fairly certain that I need some sort of Javascript that stores the dimensions of each image piece as it loads, then adjusts the dimensions of the div to those dimensions. I'm not experienced enough in Javascript to achieve this, however.

Thank you to all who take a crack at this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To adjust the dimension of lightbox you can use additional function to find the height, width of the image being displayed and can apply these to the lightbox window.
I have created a fiddle for this, please see here:
function to calculate and apply dimensions:

```
function adjustDimensions(current){
    var H = $('img','#slideshow ul > li:eq(' + current + ')').height();
    var W = $('img','#slideshow ul > li:eq(' + current + ')').width();
    if($('h5','#slideshow ul > li:eq(' + current + ')').length>0){
     H = H+20;   
    }
    $('#slideshow').animate({width:W+'px',height:H+'PX'},1000);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lokeshpahal/yX4NP/2/

Comment: Holy cow dude! This works wonderfully! I know I already marked you off as the answer and such, so you do not have to answer this, but is there a way of making the height/width responsive? Just in a way where they are not clipping off the edge since the page is fixed?

Comment: The site I'm trying to reference from is this: http://www.ashleydotsonart.portfoliobox.me/

Comment: to make this responsive you have to do some changes in the lightbox HTML structure and have to put outer div to 100% width and 100% height, this would change as per the dimensions of the window.

Comment: Sorry to sound completely noobish (though I sort of am), but I do not understand what I would need to change. My outer div is already 100% height and width, and what simpler way to get a image, title and navigation centered then by placing them in a div? Admittedly, having the div wrap to the images instead of the image reacting to the div is causing problems in the creation of a responsive site, but I did not know how to center the nav and force the title to line up with the left edge of the image - especially with such drastically different dimensions -  any other way.